# In WPF, how can I see if a point falls within a closed geometry?

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, hittest

Using custom rendering of a UIElement in WPF based on two, non-touching closed geometries.  I'm trying to determine which of the two the user has clicked on.  Is there any API which you can ask if a point falls within the specified closed geometry?

Comment: If you already have instances of `Geometry`, then you can use the `FillContains` method. It has some overloads, one of which accepts a `Point`.

Comment: Holy crap! How did I miss something that simple?  But why did you put this as a comment instead of an answer?  Do so (and throw a simple example there for others) and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: sorry I'm a bit lazy, you can freely add your own answer as well as the example you have :).

Comment: Would love to know why this was voted down.